# Tabs are not coming in layout of android studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tabbed-activity

I am trying to create tabs in my layout. But instead of showing tab it is showing the below screen in design:

[image]

Below is the code:

```
**activity_mail.xml**

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout2">
    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/white"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;

import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   /* private TabAdapter adapter;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;*/
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new TabAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),
                MainActivity.this));
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}
}
```

**Tab1Fragment.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

public class Tab1Fragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String ARG_PAGE = "ARG_PAGE";

    private int mPage;
    public static Tab1Fragment newInstance(int page) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, page);
        Tab1Fragment fragment = new Tab1Fragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mPage = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) view;
        textView.setText("Fragment #" + mPage);
        return view;
    }
}
```

**TabAdapter.Java**

```
import android.content.Context;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;

public class TabAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    final int PAGE_COUNT = 3;
    private String tabTitles[] = new String[] { "Tab1", "Tab2", "Tab3" };
    private Context context;
    public TabAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
        super(fm);
        this.context = context;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return Tab1Fragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        // Generate title based on item position
        return tabTitles[position];
    }
}
```

**fragment_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.main.PlaceholderFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/section_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:text="@string/sparta"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Also when trying to run it in my mobile, it is showing error something like:

android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView

Please suggest the way to solve this issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54527513/13600868

Answer (score 1):

You're using deprecated design support `AppBarLayout`, You need to replace it with androidx library , so replace `android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout` with `com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout` in your layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp">
        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="fixed" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />
</LinearLayout>
```

For the `android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView`, please post the entire stack trace.

**UPDATE**

> tab names are not coming. only green background of the tablayout is shown.

this is odd behavior, as I you already override `getPageTitle` in the adapter.. I just suggest not to use a hard-coded array of Strings in the adapter, instead add the tab titles in the `strings.xml`

Strings.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="tab1">Tab1</string>
    <string name="tab2">Tab2</string>
    <string name="tab3">Tab3</string>
</resources>
```

Adapter

```
public class TabAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    final int PAGE_COUNT = 3;
  //  private String tabTitles[] = new String[] { "Tab1", "Tab2", "Tab3" };
    private int[] tabTitles = new int[]{R.string.tab1, R.string.tab2, R.string.tab3};

    private Context context;
    public TabAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
        super(fm);
        this.context = context;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return Tab1Fragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        // Generate title based on item position
       // return tabTitles[position];
        
       return context.getString(tabTitles[position]);

    }
}
```

Please have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38511260/tablayout-not-displaying-tab-title-on-marshmallow/41847301) that might be relevant.

**UPDATE 2**

Try to add those listeners

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new TabAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),
            MainActivity.this));
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    // listeners
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(viewPager));


}
```

if not working , try to set the current item of the `ViewPager`

```
viewPager.setCurrentItem(itemPosition);
```

Comment: thanks zain, as commented, tab names are not coming. only green background of the tablayout is shown. pls suggest.

Comment: @shCoder thanks for comment, I updated the answer with that .. wish it works

Comment: tried, but issue is still there. Nothing showing in tab layout.

Comment: @shCoder please check again, I am doubt that could fix it, but just give it a try

Comment: hi zain, listener did not worked. where to set the current item of the ViewPager?

Comment: Hi shCoder, you can call it after `tabLayout.setupWithViewPager()` but I think it's not the problem .. also add a break point at `return context.getString(tabTitles[position]);` and debug your app to check if the `getPageTitle` really get called or not

Answer (score 1):

After androidX, support library are removed,
so you need to use material design which help you.

Replace your appbar with below code

```
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="50dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
     android:id="@+id/appBarLayout2">
```

this will help you.

Comment: thanks @webaddicted, however still the tab name is not coming. Only green background is there.pls suggest